# Android Wear emulator: "No longer connected to network"

Tags: android-emulator, android-wear

I've been using a Android Wear 1.4 (Android 6.0.1) emulator for some time, and the following notification has appeared out of the blue:

> No longer connected to network, a factory reset is required.

[image: Notification]

An action with the same text appears next to it, but tapping on it has no effect.

[image: Notification action]

Android Wear emulator is running [the following versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGr5e.png):

- Android Wear 1.4.0.2505969
- Google Play services 8.4.89 (2428711-574)
- Android OS 6.0.1

I've seen Reddit threads reporting the same problem: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidWear/comments/33vehg/no_longer_connected_to_network_a_factory_reset_is/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/moto360/comments/33td8u/this_notification_appeared_on_my_watch_today_and/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidWear/comments/37kgh1/511_yesterday_today_no_longer_connected_to/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/moto360/comments/3diak7/no_longer_connected_to_network_a_factory_reset_is/).

What's causing this? If I wipe user data, can I expect this to return?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this behavior occurs when you attach a different host device to pair with the emulator, for instance when switching between connecting two phones to your computer with pairing enabled.

The Android Wear app itself then displays the status of the emulator as "Trying to connect…" and the connection is refused between the emulator and the new device. The problem goes away once you've attached the original device that you first used with pairing to the emulator, or wiping data on the emulator and pairing it with the new device.